# Sticky footer displaying through content with screen resize

Tags: html, css

Please refer to my site http://www.vault-x.com

I have applied a "sticky footer" technique from this tutorial (http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

It however does not work when the browser window is resized vertically. I cannot work out why this is happening.

Comment: It works for me. You should most likely include the browser for which this doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're columns are floated, which means it gives no height to the content element. Add a `<div>` with `clear: both` after your `#r_column` element and it will fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the response.